# Search Criteria/Filter classes in Domain layer or Presentation layer?

Tags: java, search, dto, presentation

We are building an enterprise app that uses Spring MVC in presentation layer, EJB in business layer and JPA for data access. The app needs to support search function for various entities based on several search criteria, as entered by user from GUI. This seems to be fairly common function in most of the enterprise app, and I am wondering if there is any design pattern/principle that provides best approach. 
For now, we are having SearchCriteria classes for each business entity (e.g. AccountSearchFilter for Account). Presentation layer builds the object of SearchCriteria class and pass it over to business layer. The business layer builds a JPA query based on the available criteria and creates a collection of entity objects. The collection is passed back to presentation layer, which is then transformed to JSON by presentation layer.

I have two problems with this design:

1. SearchCriteria classes are part of business layer, but they are used by presentation layer as well.
2. Business layer returns collections of business entities to presentation layer.

I don't like to share classes among presentation and business layers, but I don't know what we can do to decouple it. I have already searched the existing posts regarding using domain objects in presentation layer, and I don't want to start a debate whether it is good or bad. I have already made up my mind that I don't want presentation layer using domain objects. Also, creating DTOs seems to duplicate code, so if that is the only feasible solution, then I may pass on this one.